# InitializationCellEvaluation does not work

Tags: notebooks, initialization

I have a notebook with a single cell that I want to start running when I launch open the notebook.  I have,

1. formatted the cell as an initialization cell
2. In the Options Inspector, Selected "Notebook" from the pull-down menu at the top and set Notebook>Evaluation>InitializationCellEvaluation to True
3. Repeated Step 2 for "runClassify.nb" in the Selection pull-down menu.  This is the name of the notebook.
4. Repeated Step 2 selection the cell and selecting Selected Cell in Selection.
5. Saved the notebook.
6. Closed the notebook.
7. Opened the notebook. I still get the panel asking me if I wanted to evaluate the initialization cells, which is not what I want.

In all this, the Apply button in the Options Inspector remains greyed out and pushing it has not effect.

I suspect there is another setting I am missing, but cannot find it anywhere in the doc or online.

The ultimate goal is to have this notebook run when I launch mathematica form the command line, so if there is another way to do this, I would appreciate hearing.  I also to want to set notebooks so they evaluate the initialization cells without asking.

This is Mathematica 13.3 running on a MacPro 13" Big Sur 11.7.4.

Comment: Open the advanced options and type "Initialization" in the search template. There are two flags set for initialization warnings. This is a security issue.

Comment: init.m is sourced when Mathematica is launched from the command line.  Depending on what things you want initialized, that may be another option for you.  On a Mac, I think the init.m is locatied at ~/Library/Mathematica/Kernel/init.m